# how can I edit the text on a button?

Tags: java, android, macos, button, android-studio-2.3

If you are reading this, I want to ask you a question (obviously). So uhh, I kinda have this problem on my emulator in android studio where the text on the button is not edited. How do I solve this? [the original thing (left) what it shows on the emulator (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDKKN.jpg)

Comment: usually, the setText(String text) method works for that

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild project?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do this from the XML code

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_addCamera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me!"/>
```

Or you can do this programmatically

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setText("Click Me!");
```

Answer (score 0):

To set Button text, you can assign
**android:text XML**
attribute for Button in layout file with the required value.

To programmatically set or change Android Button text, then pass the specified string to the method Button.
**setText(new_string_value)**